# Get Product ID and Variation ID from an Order ID from outside wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to PHP/MYSQL query WooCommerce **Product ID/Variation ID** from **Order ID**

- If the product(s) in the order is/are simple get product ID(s)
- If the product(s) in the order is/are variable get Variation ID(s)
- If both (simple and variable) get both (product ID(s) and Variation ID(s))

NOTE: The script I am coding is independent of WordPress.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using various aspects of the WooCommerce API, this can be accomplished using some version of the following.

```
$order_id = XXX;

$order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); //returns WC_Order if valid order 
$items = $order->get_items();   //returns an array of WC_Order_item or a child class (i.e. WC_Order_Item_Product)

foreach( $items as $item ) {

    //returns the type (i.e. variable or simple)
    $type = $item->get_type();

    //the product id, always, no matter what type of product
    $product_id = $item->get_product_id();

    //a default
    $variation_id = false;

    //check if this is a variation using is_type
    if( $item->is_type('variable') ) {
        $variation_id = $item->get_variation_id();
    }

    //more code
}
```

Note the documentation,

[`wc_get_order();`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wp-content/images/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_order.html)

[`WC_Order();`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wp-content/images/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html)

[`WC_Order_Item();`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item.html)

[`WC_Order_Item_Product();`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Product.html)

Comment: Careful, I'm afraid `$item->get_type()` won't return **variable** or **simple** but **line_item**

Comment: I wish I had seen @PabloSGPacheco's comment sooner. is_type indeed returns 'line_item' and proves unhelpful. It is probably best to just use `$product_id = $item->get_product_id()` and `$product_variation_id = $item->get_variation_id()`.

Comment: @ericK Glad my comment was useful. Exactly, if I'm not wrong, if you check for `$item->get_variation_id()` in a item which is not a variable product, you get zero. Maybe this is a more reliable approach indeed

Comment: If you want the product id if simple and the variation id if it's a variation, then you can use this: `$pid = $item->get_variation_id() ? $item->get_variation_id() : $item->get_product_id();`

Comment: I flagged this answer for mod intervention, as it is indeed completely incorrect. get_type cannot be used to ascertain type of product as it will always return "line_item".

Comment: To check if product is variable - just check if $item->get_variation_id() returns empty or not. if( $item->get_variation_id() ) { echo 'The product is variable'; }

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in note "The script I am coding is independent of WordPress".
Then there will be a query that you can use 
To get list of variation id from product id.
SELECT ID  FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_parent` = "PRODUCT_ID" AND `post_type` LIKE 'product_variation'